# Mongodb Find Query "where" Billing Address is Equal to Delivery Address

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

Im just wondering is it possible to do a where clause like your able to do in MYSQL in  `db.mydb.find()`
Example SQL Query

```
Select * from TBL_customers where Deliveryaddress = Billingadress
```

Is it possible to something similar in Mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $where operator does this, for example db.customers.find( { $where: "this.deliveryAddress == this.billingAddress" } );

More details in the mongo docs here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where